# How to do Countifs in R

Tags: r, data.table, countif

Data:

```
set.seed(42)
df1 = data.frame(
  Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2018-01-01"),as.Date("2018-01-30"),1),
  value = sample(1:30),
  Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 30, replace = TRUE)
)

df2 = data.frame(
  Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2018-01-01"),as.Date("2018-01-30"),7)
)
```

For sum if data falls within range this works ([from my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55354071/680068)):

```
library(data.table)

df1$start <- df1$Date
df1$end <- df1$Date

df2$start <- df2$Date
df2$end <- df2$Date + 6

setDT(df1, key = c("start", "end"))
setDT(df2, key = c("start", "end"))

d = foverlaps(df1, df2)[, list(mySum = sum(value)), by = Date ]
```

How can I do countif ?

because when I try

```
d = foverlaps(df1, df2)[, list(mySum = count(value)), by = Date ]
```

I get error

> no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: Where is that `count` function from? `dplyr`? Related, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809166/count-number-of-rows-within-each-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = foverlaps(df1, df2)[, .N, by = Date]
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `.N`:

```
foverlaps(df1, df2)[, list(myCount = .N), by = Date ]
#          Date myCount
# 1: 2018-01-01       7
# 2: 2018-01-08       7
# 3: 2018-01-15       7
# 4: 2018-01-22       7
# 5: 2018-01-29       2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count the number of rows per Date, you can try `.N`

```
foverlaps(df1, df2)[, .(mysum = .N), by = Date ]
         Date mysum
1: 2018-01-01     7
2: 2018-01-08     7
3: 2018-01-15     7
4: 2018-01-22     7
5: 2018-01-29     2
```

If you want the count of unique values per Date you can try `uniqueN()`

```
foverlaps(df1, df2)[, .(mysum = uniqueN(value)), by = Date ]
         Date mysum
1: 2018-01-01     7
2: 2018-01-08     7
3: 2018-01-15     7
4: 2018-01-22     7
5: 2018-01-29     2
```

Both `.N` and `uniqueN()` are from `{data.table}`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `list(mySum = count(value))` try `c(mySum = count(value))`. The Code runs for me then.

```
d2 <-  foverlaps(df1, df2)[, c(mySum = count(value)), by = Date ]
```

Comment: Runs for me without problems. What version of data.table are you using?

Comment: latest version.

Comment: Ah. I see my problem, you are using count() from dplyr while I had the plyr count() loaded. With count() from plyr it works. Please add all necessary packages for the example to work next time